# Extract Sentences from A String

Tags: python, nltk

I am working on a machine learning chatbot project which uses google's speech recognition api.

Now my problem is, when I say 2 or more sentences in one command, speech recognition api returns all sentences in one string, without any fullstop or commas. As a result, it has become harder to seperate sentences. For example, if I say,

`Take a photo. Tell me about today's weather. Open Google Chrome.`

the speech recognition api returnes:
`take a photo tell me about todays weather open Google Chrome`

so, my chatbot takes this full string as one sentence.

Is there any way to extract sentences from a string like the one above?

(BTW, I am using Python)

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to say multiple commands say words like "and" and split the command based on that word. Now loop through the list and pass each value to your execute function.

If the variable `command` stores your value split it using `command.split(" and ")`

I had previously answered a similar question take a look at it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65872940/12279129

Comment: thanks for your answer but, I had already implememted what you just said. But saying "and"  every time feels weired to me. That's why I am interested doing this using NLP. It would be helpful if you can tell me how I would do it using nlp.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try different approaches to solve the problem:

1. A Naive solution

---

I don't know how your system works for now but if you are just looking for some subsentences you could search in the full set of sentences if there is what you are looking for.
i.e.

```
input_str = "Take a photo turn on fan".lower()

if "take a photo" in input_str :
 print("Just took a photo!")
if "turn on fan" in input_str :
 print("Just turned the fan on!")
```

Ofc you could also select a separator word (like and, furthermore, ..) and use it as separator.

2. A more advanced solution

---

You could use a NLP library (i.e. [spacy](https://spacy.io/)) and perform entity recognition so that you can isolate verbs from noun and so on.
After that you could evemtually make use of [stemming and lemmatization](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) to further generalize the recognition.

You could also perform many intermediate step with different NLP techniques like stopwords removal.

3. Try auto punctuation from API

---

Maybe you can try [enabling](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation) automatic punctuation in the speech to text api and see if this works good enough for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your 2nd and 3rd solution was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Google Cloud Speech doesn't provide Natural Language Understanding and you are stuck parsing text transcripts.

You can of course create the natural language understanding component yourself, either by using simple regular expressions or using something like [Rasa](https://rasa.com/), but there's a smarter way, too.

[Speechly](https://www.speechly.com/) provides you with everything you need to create voice user interfaces on Android, iOS or web. It returns you not only the transcript, but also actionable intents and entities that makes it a lot easier to create something a bit more complex. The best part is that it's free for up to 20 hours a month.

You can see a very simple example on how it works for instance for creating search experiences [here](https://www.speechly.com/solutions/voice-search/). However, the basic idea is always the same: create a model and test that it returns correct intents for your speech input. After you are done, you integrate it to your app by looping through the returned results and whenever you get the correct intent, react in your application as needed. It's actually very simple.

Answer (score -1):

You can use split method

Let your string is A

```
X = A.split('.')
```

It will make X a list which will contain items as sentences

Comment: There are no dots in a string that google api returns so I think you should replace it with space: X = A.split(' ')